# Embedded Resource folder path for HttpRootDirectory

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource, httpserver

I am using a [uHttpSharp](https://github.com/Code-Sharp/uHttpSharp) library for creating an embedded http-server. This has a FileHandler method for hosting a folder(contains index.htm, main.js, style.css etc.) to the server. It works fine with the absolute path I gave to `FileHandler.HttpRootDirectory`. But I want to put the folder as Resource so that it can be accessed within the project. I added my folder in the Project Folder and changed files type to Embedded Resource. Now I want the internal path for assigning it to `HttpRootDirectory` or some other way.

PS: I tried this,

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

but it gives the file name, not the dir path.